# How can I simulate ivy.retrieve.pattern in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to resolve dependencies from a legacy ivy repository using gradle v3.1.

The artifacts are stored using a pattern like: 
    '[organisation]/[module]/[artifact]-revision.[ext]'

In the old ant build the artifacts are retrieved with a retrieve.pattern of: 
    '[artifact]-revision.[ext]'

Meaning that the "type" is stripped off the retrieved artifact filename.

I can resolve the artifacts properly using gradle, but many of them end up with filenames like *-jar.jar.

For most dependencies the filename does not matter, but unfortunately there are a few places where they do (for example in a generated descriptor for a resource adapter in an .ear that is being referenced from somewhere else).

Is there a way to "rename" the dependencies so they end up in gradle with the adjusted name? - Just like the ivy.retrieve.pattern works in ivy.